# Filling in missing numbers from an array

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to fill in the missing numbers from a user input (which is stored in an array. For example, if the user inputs 9, 5, 2, 7, 1. My program must output the missing numbers which are 3, 4, 6, 8.

You can see the missing numbers are bolded: 1, 2, **3**, **4**, 5, **6**, 7, **8**

However, my code doesn't seem to run. The while loop doesn't function. I feel like my logic is working, but its not outputting anything.

```
void missing_num(int length, int numbers[]) { // length is the length of the array

// A function which finds the biggest number the user inputed
int big_num_answer = biggest_num(length, numbers);

// A functon which finds the smallest number the user inputed
int small_num_answer = smallest_num(length, numbers);

int has_been_used = 0;
int i = 0;
int start_num = small_num_answer;
while(start_num <= big_num_answer) {

    if(numbers[i] == start_num + 1) {
        start_num += 1;
        has_been_used = 1;
    } else if(i >= length && has_been_used == 0) {
        printf("%d", start_num + 1);
    }

    i++;
    if (i > length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This is probably the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Spent about 30 minutes trying to. Im stuck

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Can you explain your logic?

Comment: @Shubham It finds the smallest and largest number from the user input (so 1 and 8). It then uses the smallest number (1) and goes through the array to find if there is a smallest_number + 1. So basically its looking for the number 2 in the array. If it finds the number 2, it does nothing until int i is greater than the array size (length). Once i is greater than the array size, int i resets to 0 and starts looking for a number in the array which is 2 + 1 (aka 3). So it repeats the process and tries to find the number 3.

Comment: @Shubham If it doesn't find the number, then it prints the number out and then once int i is greater than the array size, it resets int i to 0

Answer (score 1):

When you're having trouble with logic it's best to just go through it line by line and see what would happen. I don't quite understand what you're trying to do in the loop so let's go through it block by block and pretend we're using 1, 2, 5, 7, 9 as an input.

```
while(start_num <= big_num_answer) {
```

Pretty straightforward. The while loop keeps going while start_num is below or equal to the largest number. start_num, in this case, is 1.

```
if(numbers[i] == start_num + 1) {
    start_num += 1;
    has_been_used = 1;
}
```

i is 0, so this line evals to if(1==2). It's skipped.

```
else if(i >= length && has_been_used == 0) 
{
    printf("%d", start_num + 1);
}
```

This evals to if(0 >= 5 AND 0=0). It's skipped and no numbers are outputted.

```
i++;
if (i > length) {
    i = 0;
}
```

i now is 1. Let's go through the loop again.

```
if(numbers[i] == start_num + 1) {
    start_num += 1;
    has_been_used = 1;
}
```

Evals to if(2==2). So now start_num = 2, and has_been_used = 1.

```
else if(i >= length && has_been_used == 0) 
{
    printf("%d", start_num + 1);
}
```

The else block is skipped entirely because the other condition was hit. And this block will never be hit again, because has_been_used has been set to 1 and you have no code that sets has_been_used back to 0. Since we ran through it now we can see at least one reason why the code doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of thing I don't understand. Anyway, here's a quick attempt:

```
static void print_with_missing(const int *array, size_t length)
{
    int last = *array;
    printf("%d", last);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < length;)
    {
        while (array[i] != last + 1)
        {
            printf(" %d", ++last);
        }
        printf(" %d", array[i]);
        last = array[i++];
    }
}
```

if called with your sample array (`{ 1, 2, 5, 7, 9 }`), the output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Note: it requires the input to be sorted, which seems to make sense. If you don't want to expose that, just call `qsort()` first inside the function, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another not too complicated idea of doing that without requiring sorted input, but providing sorted output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numbers[1024];
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;
size_t n;

int main(void) {
    while (n < 1024)
    {
        // use something better then scanf for "production quality" code
        if (scanf("%d", numbers + n++) != 1) break;
        if (numbers[n-1] > max) max = numbers[n-1];
        if (numbers[n-1] < min) min = numbers[n-1];
    }
    if (max > min && max - min)
    {
        size_t rangesize = max - min - 1;

        // use an array of "markers" for the numbers present in the input
        char *used = calloc(1, rangesize);
        if (!used) return 1;

        // set the markers
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > min && numbers[i] < max)
            {
                used[numbers[i]-min-1] = 1;
            }
        }

        // and use them for output
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rangesize; ++i)
        {
            if (!used[i])
            {
                printf("%d ", (int)i + min + 1);
            }
        }

        puts("");
        free(used);
    }
}
```

[online demo](https://ideone.com/LLHNYs)

Answer (score 0):

Let's disect this:

```
int start_num = small_num_answer;
while(start_num <= big_num_answer) {
```

you want to loop from the smallest to the biggest number so far so good.

```
    if(numbers[i] == start_num + 1) {
```

trouble starts here I am not entirly sure but I think you want to check, whether the next number is also in the array but you only check `numbers[i]` instead of all elements of `numbers`.

```
        start_num += 1;
        has_been_used = 1;
```

If the current number is there you increase your integer to search by one. And set a flag that it is in the array. But you never reset this value. So this will always be 1.

```
    } else if(i >= length && has_been_used == 0) {
        printf("%d", start_num + 1);
    }
```

here you check if the array is still in bounds (way to late as you used `numbers[i]` without a check before. And check the (not working) flag, whether the number was in the input.

```
    i++;
    if (i > length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

At last you check that `i`is not larger then `length`, which is a good idea but `i = length` is already out of bounds as we start to count at `0`.

---

I try to give you something in the spirit of your approach, but you will need a second loop to iterate `i`through the whole array.

```
while(start_num < big_num_answer) {

  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){ //iterate though the whole array

    if(numbers[i] == start_num + 1) {
        has_been_used = 1;
    }
  }

  if (has_been_used == 0){
    printf("%d", start_num + 1); //print if not found
  }

  has_been_used = 0; // reset flag
  start_num++; // next elelemt
}
```